# Stretch inner div to match container of variable height. Impossible?

Tags: html, css, height

I like to think I'm a pretty good... well, passable... web developer.  I've built probably... IDK, 50 web sites, with a good amount of Flash and Javascript, and a few database-backed applications, and done enough graphic design to be able to competently fake it :)

I've run across this problem half a dozen times in my career: How do you set an inner div to 100% height of the containing div when the container's height is variable?  I know you can do it with Javascript or use faux columns, but I swear to dog, if there is no way to do it with pure HTML/CSS I'm going to be very disappointed in life and the W3C :(

Here be the mockup matey:  http://random.siliconrockstar.com/heightTest/

See, the inner div #content pushes #container down.  I want the pink part, #shadow, to be the same height as #content.  The usual case when I run into this problem is with designers who don't know anything about web development and use a lot of drop shadows; just pretend the pink part is a dropshadow I need to extend down the right edge of #content.

Aside: yes, I know you can do dropshadows with CSS now, even in IE with some hacks, but in this case I have design issues preventing me from doing that.

Is this really impossible without Javascript? :(

Answer (score 2):

If IE6 is no topic, you can do:

```
#shadow{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F69;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome.  Doesn't work in my XP/IE7 VM but I don't care, it works in IE8+ :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible without JavaScript but according  what you need you can use this kind of stuff: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: Um... yeah, this kind of seems like more of a confusing hack than just using javascript.  Thanks for replying though, it's a very interesting article.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that maybe the new css3 stuff will start to help with this:
e.g.

```
.container { display: box; box-align: stretch; box-orient: vertical; }  
.container div { box-flex: 1; }
```

(you may need the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes for this)

Answer (score 0):

For the pink one

```
#shadow{
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, I assume because you can't inherit a height that is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Well. there is a number of ways to do it. Oldest one is to use big bottom padding and big negative bottom margin as as explained there: http://www.alphapapahotel.com/equal-height-div-columns-100-percent/css/

But this way have it's drawbacks: You need to set parent's element overflow to hidden to make it work. So if you inner absolute positioned elements to overflow it, you can't. Also if area inside "overflow: hidden;" div have anchor (<a name="first-paragraph"></a> for example) the area inside the div will be scrolled, not the page.

Another way is to use table-cell property: http://jsfiddle.net/8UPeR/ . Didn't work in older browsers through.

But to just stretch #shadow to the height of the #content there are easier ways, like using pseudo-elemens ( http://jsfiddle.net/PWMsz/1/ ) or "position: absolute" as in topek's example.